# Adding geoJSON layer to a google map in Meteor.js

Tags: meteor, geojson

I have a plain google map that displays fine, while running in Meteor with bootstrap, and this plugin - https://github.com/dburles/meteor-google-maps I am new to Meteor.js and can't figure how to load in some local trails data from a city open geoJSON file. I've been able to do it in plain javascript using loadGeoJson() but having a hard time incorporating this in meteor.

The template and javascript are below.

```js
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Meteor.startup(function() {
    GoogleMaps.load();
  });

  Template.map.helpers({
    exampleMapOptions: function() {
      // Make sure the maps API has loaded
      if (GoogleMaps.loaded()) {
        // Map initialization options
        return {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(43.613, -116.211),
          zoom: 12
        };
      }
    }
  });

  Template.map.onCreated(function() {
    // We can use the `ready` callback to interact with the map API once the map is ready.
    GoogleMaps.ready('exampleMap', function(map) {
      // Add a marker to the map once it's ready
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: map.options.center,
        map: map.instance
      });
    });
}
```

```html
<template name="map">
 <div class="container-fluid text-center">
  <div class="map-container">
      {{> googleMap name="exampleMap" options=exampleMapOptions}}
    </div>
 </div>
</template>
```

So with plain html and js/jquery I'm able to pull in the geo layer with this:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var mapOptions = {
        center: { lat: 43.618331, lng:  -116.219650},
        zoom: 12
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('myMap'),
                    mapOptions);

    map.data.loadGeoJson('http://opendata.cityofboise.org/datasets/6958bea81e2c482b89f917de9dd4f952_1.geojson');
});
```

I'm trying to translate that into 'meteor'.

Thanks to Ethaan's advice and some work, I found a solution.  I ditched the meteor plugin AND Google Maps. I went with Leaflet and OpenStreetMaps - leaflet's geoJSON integration looked easier to deal with to me. Then played with Meteor's .rendered method. I used jquery's ajax() to grab the data and store it in a variable. Success! Here's the JS -

```
Template.map.rendered = function() {
      var map = L.map('map_container', {maxZoom: 19, zoom: 13, zoomControl: false, center: ['43.6167','-116.2000']});
      map.attributionControl.setPrefix('');
      L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png').addTo(map);
      L.Icon.Default.imagePath = 'packages/leaflet/images';

      var theData = new L.geoJson();
      theData.addTo(map);

      $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        url: "data/myDataFile.json",
        success: function(data) {
            $(data.features).each(function(key, data) {
            theData.addData(data);
            });
        }
        }).error(function() {});
}
```

Comment: So the above code works fine? What specifically is the problem or needed solution/addition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some ways to load a map into meteor, but the meteor way to knows when the map is ready is taking off the  `$(document).ready(function(){});` and instead use a onRendered function, you don't need a helper at all, the only you need is a init function and a onRender (just to be sure that the `<div>` with the map is ready.

I made a Demo here is the [Source Code on Github](https://github.com/Ethaan/Meteorjs-sample-map), it use a older version of `meteor (1.2.1)`, but the only think that changes its the rendered function

I never use that `meteor-gogole-maps` for me putting the CDN into the `<head>` works ;p

Seems you are asking a way to use gmaps on meteor, i think thats all i can do for now, also there is no errors given.

Good Luck

Comment: Thanks!  Appreciate your time and advice!

Comment: Success achieved!  Added my solution to the question. Thanks again for pointing me in the right direction.